# Select a count with some conditions

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-9.4

Using Postgres 9.4, I have a table `page_views` which has a `page` column. I'd like to select all the distinct pages and have a count before them and sort them descending. I'd also like to have a minimum count of 20 in the past 24 hours. So that it looks like this:

```
120 / home
 56 / about
 24 / locations
```

I was thinking:

```
select count(*),page from page_views group by page where count(*) > 20;
```

but this does not work. How to do this?

Comment: Look up the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: You missed the 24 hours condition in your `where` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear whether you want the total count or the count in the past 24 hours. For the latter:

```
SELECT count(*), page
FROM   page_views
GROUP  BY 2
WHERE  created_at >= now() - interval '24 hours' -- guessing column
HAVING count(*) > 20
ORDER  BY 1 DESC;
```

The condition `count(*) > 20` has to go into the [`HAVING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP).

You did not provide a table definition. Guessing you have a `created_at` to store the event time.

Total counts, but only for pages having a minimum count of 20 in the past 24 hours:

```
SELECT count(*), page
FROM  (  
    SELECT page
    FROM   page_views
    GROUP  BY 1
    WHERE  created_at >= now() - interval '24 hours'
    HAVING count(*) > 20
    ) x
JOIN   page_views p USING (page)
GROUP  BY 2
ORDER  BY 1 DESC;
```